# Store ID from a dropdown list

Tags: c#, sql, dropdown

I have been working on this for a while but seems I can't figure this out. So I have a dropdown list called ddStudent where the textField value is from a sql table I made called 'Student from a column called 'firstName'. Now I used the 'studentID' as the value field.

Here is where I am having the issue. I want to execute my stored procedure that takes studentID as a paramter but I don't understand how to store the actual student ID into the parameter.

Here is what I have so far-

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selValClass = Convert.ToInt32(ddClassNames.SelectedValue);
        int selValStudent = Convert.ToInt32(ddStudents.SelectedValue);

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procRegStudent", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", selValStudent);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classID", selValClass);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
```

and here is my code for databinding-

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT studentID, firstName, lastName, ssn, address, city, state, zip FROM Student ", con);

            con.Open();

            ddStudents.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddStudents.DataTextField = "firstName";
            ddStudents.DataValueField = "studentID";
            ddStudents.DataBind();

        }
```

Now my question is, is there a way I can store the actual studentID from the dropdown list when I select it? For some reason when I do this, the page reloads and selects the first student ID for a student I didn't select. I'm not exactly sure what's going on.

Thanks.

EDIT-

I wanted to make sure I clarify-

I have 3 students in my student dropdown. When I select student 3 (with student ID 3), the first student in the dropdownlist is being passed as the parameter and I can't tell why.

Comment: Could you please send me the design view for the ddStudent DropDownList,I want to check something before saying my answer :) !

Comment: @FreedomDeveloper Do you mean of the table that is associated to it?

Comment: No I mean the HTML view of your dropdownlist control
which is something like that :
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>

Comment: @FreedomDeveloper Here you go. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6bd355l3xos0e3/Class%20Reg%20design%20view.png?dl=0)

Comment: @FreedomDeveloper Here is the aspx.


               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStudents" runat="server" DataTextField = "firstName" DataValueField = "studentID"></asp:DropDownList>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is logical for Dropdownlist control because your dropdownlist missed to have a defaultitem to render when it comes back from the server.The soultion is very simple you should add a default list item to be the default value when the page loads

Here I made a simple example to how can we solve this issue :

**in the Page.aspx:**

> ```
>     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStudents" runat="server" DataTextField = "firstName" DataValueField = "studentID" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
>         <asp:ListItem Text="===Select Student===" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
>
>     </asp:DropDownList> 
>
>     <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
>     <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
> ```

**in the Page.aspx.cs:**

> ```
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (!IsPostBack)
>         {
>             BindDropDown();
>
>         }
>
>     }
>
>     private void BindDropDown()
>     {
>         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>         dt.Columns.Add("studentID", typeof(int));
>         dt.Columns.Add("firstName", typeof(string));
>
>         dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
>         dt.Rows[0]["studentID"] = 1;
>         dt.Rows[0]["firstName"] = "Markus";
>
>
>         dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
>         dt.Rows[1]["studentID"] = 2;
>         dt.Rows[1]["firstName"] = "Arthur";
>
>
>         ddStudents.DataSource = dt;
>         ddStudents.DataBind();
>     }
>
>     protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (ddStudents.SelectedIndex > 0)
>         {
>             lblMessage.Text = String.Format("You selected {0} with Number : {1}", ddStudents.SelectedItem.Text,ddStudents.SelectedValue);
>         }
>     }
> ```

**Hint:** I marked the dropdownlist AppendDataBoundItems Property to true just to tell the dropdownlist to include the default listitem when the data binded..

I hope my code helps you solving your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

int selValStudent = int.Parse(this.ddStudents.SelectedValue);

and put your

BindDropDown();

into your postback